# Compare current and last value in list

Tags: c#, winforms

There is a moving average suppose: 2, 4, 6 , 8 , 10...n;

Then add the current value (10) to list

```
List<int>numHold  = new List<int>(); 
numhold.Add(currentvalue);
```

Inside the list:

the current value is added

10
and so on
20
30
40 etc

by using

```
var lastdigit = numHold[numhold.Count -1];
```

I can get the last digit but the output is

current: 10 last: 10
current: 20 last: 20

the output should be
current: 20 last: 10

Thanks

Comment: And the question is? (I can't see a question mark anywhere in your message...)

Comment: You add something from the list, read it back and then you are surprised that what you stored is what you read back?

Comment: Your question would become clearer if you posted the code in full.

Comment: What's the point of this? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Use `numHold[numhold.Count -2]` to get the next to last but check if the list contains at least two at that point.

Comment: the meaning of `last` and `current` is unclear. if you add value to the list the current would be the last item added. or by `last` you mean one before the last item added?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, C# indexers start from `0`, so the first element has index `0`. On the other hand, `Count`/`Length` will use `1` for one element. So your

```
numHold[numhold.Count - 1]
```

actually takes the last element in the list. If you need the one before that, you need to use `- 2` - though be careful you do not reach outside of the bounds of the list (something like `Math.Max(0, numhold.Count - 2)` might be appropriate).

Answer (score 0):

You can also store the values in separate variables:

```
List<int> nums = new List<int> { 1 };

int current = 1;
int last = current;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    last = current;
    current = i * 2;
    nums.Add(current);
}

Console.WriteLine("Current: {0}", current);
Console.WriteLine("Last: {0}", last);
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is so unclear, but if ur using moving average to draw a line graph  you would use a circular buffer which can be implemented by urself utilizing an object that contains an array of specified size, and the next available position.  You could also download a nuget package that already has it done.

Answer (score 0):

A relatively simple way to calculate a moving average is to use a circular buffer to hold the last N values (where `N` is the number of values for which to compute a moving average).

For example:

```
public sealed class MovingAverage
{
    private readonly int _max;
    private readonly double[] _numbers;

    private double _total;

    private int _front;
    private int _count;

    public MovingAverage(int max)
    {
        _max = max;
        _numbers = new double[max];
    }

    public double Average
    {
        get { return _total / _count; }
    }

    public void Add(double value)
    {
        _total += value;

        if (_count == _max)
            _total -= _numbers[_front];
        else
            ++_count;

        _numbers[_front] = value;
        _front = (_front+1)%_max;
    }
};
```

which you might use like this:

```
var test = new MovingAverage(11);

for (int i = 0; i < 25; ++i)
{
    test.Add(i);
    Console.WriteLine(test.Average);
}
```

Note that this code is optimised for speed. After a large number of iterations, you might start to get rounding errors. You can avoid this by adding to class `MovingAverage` a slower method to calculate the average instead of using the `Average` property:

```
    public double AccurateAverage()
    {
        double total = 0;

        for (int i = 0, j = _front; i < _count; ++i)
        {
            total += _numbers[j];

            if (--j < 0)
                j = _max - 1;
        }

        return total/_count;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Your last item will always be at position 0.

```
List<int>numHold  = new List<int>(); 
numHold.add(currentvalue); //Adding 10

numHold[0]; // will contain 10

numHold.add(currentvalue); //Adding 20

numHold[0]; // will contain 10

numHold[numhold.Count - 1]; // will contain 20
```

the better way to get first and last are

```
numHold.first(); //Actually last in your case
numHold.last(); //first in your case
```

Comment: I believe you wanted to write `Add`, `First`and `Last`

Comment: -1: Why will the last item always be at position zero? Why should the second .add() call add twenty instead of ten (as mentioned in the comment) if the variable value didn't change? All used lower case method names are not existing in the .Net framework.

Comment: numHold.Add just adds a new item in the list....
Visual studio will tell the exact case, so I didn't bother it.